# Use Orientdb graph mode in a Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, orientdb, graph-databases

I'm trying to use OrientDB in my Spring MVC project.

I tried to use spring-data-orientdb project but there is no support for GraphDB mode.

Then I found an example project on GitHub but it uses OrientDB in Object mode that make easy to map POJOs in Documents.

But instead I need OrientDB in **Graph mode** so that I can perform traverse queries.

What is the best approach to do that? Should I write mapping code between Edge/Vertex and my domain model?